# Is there an equivalent for Springs Resource in Micronaut?

Tags: java, micronaut

I am migrating a tiny Spring Boot application to Micronaut 1.0.1 and I was wondering if there is an equivalent for `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` and their implementation such as `ClasspathResource`?

In Spring Boot I inject a resource into a service using its constructor.

```
@Service
public class MyService() {

    private final Resource resource;

    public MyService(Resource resource) { this.resource = resource; }
}
```

How can I do this in Micronaut?

```
@Singleton
public class MyService() {

    private final Resource resource;

    @Inject
    public MyService(Resource resource) { this.resource = resource; }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Micronaut you can use `io.micronaut.core.io.ResourceLoader` variants, such as `io.micronaut.core.io.scan.ClassPathResourceLoader` or `io.micronaut.core.io.file.FileSystemResourceLoader`. One option to get them is via `io.micronaut.core.io.ResourceResolver`:

```java
ClassPathResourceLoader loader = new ResourceResolver().getLoader(ClassPathResourceLoader.class).get();
Optional<URL> resource = loader.getResource("classpath:foo/bar.txt");
```

Answer (score 4):

[`ResourceLoader`](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) works well but you can do better. In Micronaut you can use [`io.micronaut.core.io.Readable`](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/core/io/Readable.html). It is roughly equivalent to Spring's `Resource`. You can also use `Readable` in [ConfigurationProperties](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-configuration/guide/index.html) and thus bind your configuration yaml/properties directly to `Readable` properties:

```yaml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: Demo
images:
  image-file: "classpath:images/bismarckia-nobilis.jpg"
  # image-file: "file:/path/to/images/bismarckia-nobilis.jpg"
  other-files:
    - "classpath:images/bismarckia-nobilis.jpg"
    - "classpath:images/bamboo.jpg"
    - "classpath:images/hibiscus.jpg"
```

I have created:

- Blog post: https://hillert.com/blog/from-resource-to-readable/
- Demo: https://github.com/ghillert/resource-readable-demo

Answer (score 3):

I used `io.micronaut.core.io.ResourceLoader`. Wired through the constructor:

```java
@Controller("root")
public class MyController {

    private final ResourceLoader loader;

    public MyController(ResourceLoader loader) {
        this.loader = loader;
    }

    @Get("/index")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String greet() throws IOException {
        return new String(loader.getResourceAsStream("index.html").get().readAllBytes());
    }
}
```

path to my `index.html`: `src/main/resources/index.html`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way

```java
@Singleton
public class MyService {

    @Value("classpath:your-file.json")
    private Readable readable;
}
```

or

```java
@Singleton
public class MyService {

    private final Readable readable;

    public MyService(@Value("classpath:your-file.json") Readable file) {
        this.readable = readable;
    }
}
```