# Micronaut list resources files

Tags: java, resources, micronaut

In spring I can use **ResourceLoader** and **ResourcePatternUtils**:

```
class Foobar {
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Autowired
    public Foobar(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    Resource[] loadResources(String pattern) throws IOException {
        return ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(resourceLoader).getResources(pattern);
    }
}
```

and use it

```
Resource[] resources = foobar.loadResources("classpath*:../../dir/*.txt");
```

How I can do it in Micronaut?

I find one solution
[Is there an equivalent for Springs Resource in Micronaut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370135/is-there-an-equivalent-for-springs-resource-in-micronaut)

ADD

```
    @Inject
    private DefaultClassPathResourceLoader resourceLoader;

...
        Stream<URL> currencyStream = resourceLoader.getResources("currency/*.json");
        long count = currencyStream.count();
...
```

But count always 0 =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent of the `Resource` interface, however you can retrieve resources in URL format.

Inject a `io.micronaut.context.env.ResourceLoader`. It has `Stream<URL> getResources(String name)`

EDIT: An example

```
resourceLoader.getResources("some/directory/test.txt")
```

Comment: Can you give small example

Comment: I added small example. I can't get all files =(

Answer (score 1):

check [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.1.2/api/io/micronaut/cli/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html)
from io.micronaut.cli.io.support;