# How to write a byte array to a cloud destination using Micronaut?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-rest

I'm converting a small Spring method to Micronaut. The purpose of this method is to write a byte array to a destination in the cloud. To identify the destination, a URI is passed as argument to the Spring method. This is the implementation using Spring:

```
    public class MyWriter{

        public MyWriter(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
            this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
        }
    
        public boolean writeToDestination(String uri, byte[] bytes) {
        
            WritableResource resource = (WritableResource) resourceLoader.getResource(uri);
    
            try (OutputStream out = resource.getOutputStream()) {
                out.write(bytes);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new WriteFileException(e);
            }
    
            return true;
         }

    }
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370135/is-there-an-equivalent-for-springs-resource-in-micronaut), I know that Micronaut doesn't have the `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` class, but it has `io.micronaut.core.io.ResourceLoader` and other variants. I have not found any Micronaut alternative to `org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource`.

I have come across `io.micronaut:micronaut-cli:2.0.0.M2`, which apparently includes a similar implementation to the Spring classes Resource and WritableResource, but every time I use that I get this error:

```
Failed to inject value for parameter [resourceLoader] of class: ResourceManager    
Message: No bean of type [io.micronaut.cli.io.support.ResourceLoader] exists.
```

I am new to Micronaut, so I am not familiar with most IO features it offers.

That being said, how do I convert the method above to Micronaut?

Comment: "The purpose of this method is to write a byte array to a destination, which could be a local file or something else in the cloud." - Would you like to see an example of writing bytes to a local file, or to something else in the cloud?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Ideally, I'd have a look at both because the method should write to the cloud but also should be testable locally (and in that case I'd use the local filesystem).

Comment: "I'd have a look at both" - The best practice for each will be different, and some might accept a proposed approach for one and not for the other.  Your question would be better served as 2 separate questions, IMO.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I gave this some more thought and edited the question to clarify that I am interested in writing to the cloud.

Comment: Do you want to write the bytes to a relational database in the cloud, some cloud storage like an S3 bucket, or something else?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I want to write the bytes to a Google Cloud Bucket.

Comment: "I want to write the bytes to a Google Cloud Bucket. " - FYI, we have published a guide at https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-object-storage-gcp-gradle-java.html which describes how to do that.

Comment: I believe I have answered your question. Can you check, upvote and accept it if it meets your requirements, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's cloud storage specifically, you should try using [Micronaut Object Storage](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-object-storage/latest/guide/).

Eg:
Install dependencies for your cloud provider

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micronaut.objectstorage</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-object-storage-aws</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Set configuration options - `src/main/resources/application-ec2.yml`

```
micronaut:
  object-storage:
    aws:
      default:
        bucket: profile-pictures-bucket
```

Inject in your controllers/services/etc. a bean of type [ObjectStorageOperations](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-object-storage/latest/api/io/micronaut/objectstorage/ObjectStorageOperations.html), the parent interface that allows you to use the API in a generic way for all cloud providers.

And use:

```
public String saveProfilePicture(String userId, Path path) {
    UploadRequest request = UploadRequest.fromPath(path, userId);
    UploadResponse<?> response = objectStorage.upload(request);
    return response.getKey();
}
```

All info above is from: [Micronaut Object Storage](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-object-storage/latest/guide/).