# What is the Micronaut equivalent of PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver

Tags: java, spring, micronaut

Have a bunch of GraphQL schema files I need to load, I would like to do something like

```
resourceResolver.getResource("classpath:graphql/**/*.graphqls")
```

In Spring this would be a use for PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - however this doesn't seem to exist in Micronaut (it briefly lived in CLI, but in 1.3.1).

What's the preferred approach? Resources will only ever be in that subdirectory.

Googling like crazy. Seems only references to people trying to recreate it without spring.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387964/997587

Comment: Wow, useless drive-by comment. :eyeroll:

Comment: When "Googling like crazy", did you come across this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53375338/14072498